# How to set desktop image to NSWindow programmatically objective c?

Tags: objective-c, macos, background-image, nswindow

How to set the desktop image to NSWindow Background image in mac os application programatically. Suppose if I click a button then whatever the desktop image is there it should apply to NSWindow Background.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cocoa: take screenshot of desktop wallpaper (without icons and windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082837/cocoa-take-screenshot-of-desktop-wallpaper-without-icons-and-windows)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32918072/1889814

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain a screen's desktop image you use methods provided by `NSWorkspace`.

The method `desktopImageURLForScreen:` returns a URL for the image file, while the method `desktopImageOptionsForScreen:` returns a dictionary of desktop image options - how images should be scaled, whether they should be tiled, etc.

Using those methods and an `NSImageView` you should be able to display the desktop image appropriately scaled, tiled and aligned as a window background. If you are supporting windows spanning screens on multi-screen systems it will be a bit more involved but the method is essentially the same.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

CRD suggestion does work if the app is not Sandboxed. If it is, then you can't do anything with `NSWorkspace.shared.desktopImageURL(for: screen)`.

you can play with Core Graphics and grab a picture of the Desktop(s):

```swift
extension NSImage {

    static func desktopPictures() -> [NSImage] {

        let info = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(.optionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID) as? [[ String : Any]]

        var images = [NSImage]()

        for window in info! {

            // we need windows owned by Dock
            let owner = window["kCGWindowOwnerName"] as! String
            if owner != "Dock" {
                continue
            }

            // we need windows named like "Desktop Picture %"
            let name = window["kCGWindowName"] as! String
            if !name.hasPrefix("Desktop Picture") {
                continue
            }

            // this belongs to a screen
            let index = window["kCGWindowNumber"] as! CGWindowID
            let cgImage = CGWindowListCreateImage(CGRect.infinite, CGWindowListOption(arrayLiteral: CGWindowListOption.optionIncludingWindow), index, CGWindowImageOption.nominalResolution)
            images.append(NSImage(cgImage: cgImage!, size: NSMakeSize(CGFloat(cgImage!.width), CGFloat(cgImage!.height))))
        }

        // return the array of Desktop images
        return images
    }
}
```

and then to get Desktop images

```swift
NSImage.desktopPictures()
```

thanks to [Cocoa: take screenshot of desktop wallpaper (without icons and windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082837/cocoa-take-screenshot-of-desktop-wallpaper-without-icons-and-windows) and [How to get window list from core-grapics API with swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30336740/how-to-get-window-list-from-core-grapics-api-with-swift)